# Proving that every natural number can be expressed as the sum of distinct Fibonacci numbers

Tags: proof-writing, induction, fibonacci-numbers

> The Fibonacci sequence $f_1, f_2, f_3, \ldots$ is defined by $f_1 = 1, f_2 = 2$, and $f_m = f_{m−1} + f_{m−2}$ for each integer $m \ge 3$. Prove that every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be expressed as the sum of distinct integers from the Fibonacci sequence.
>
> **Note:** You may use without proof that the Fibonacci sequence is an increasing sequence

I am stuck in this question. Are we supposed to use strong induction here? I am trying it but get stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is known as [Zeckendorf's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Use strong induction, assuming this is true up to some $n-1 \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, for $n$, find the largest Fibonacci member $f$ below $n$ and apply strong induction to $n - f$.